# Half of the records are lost when iterating over a JSON list

Tags: python, json, iterator

```
[{"attributes": {"type": "Silo__c", "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Silo__c/b0L36000007xRItEAM"}, "Id": "a0M36000007xRItEAM", "OwnerId": "00536000002yKlTAAU", "IsDeleted": false, "Name": "Fresh", "Landing_Stop_Date__c": null, "Service_Exit_Date__c": null},{"attributes": {"type": "Silo__c", "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Silo__c/b0L36000007xRItEAM"}, "Id": "a0M36000007xRItEAM", "OwnerId": "00536000002yKlTAAU", "IsDeleted": false, "Name": "Fresh", "Landing_Stop_Date__c": null, "Service_Exit_Date__c": null},{"attributes": {"type": "Silo__c", "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Silo__c/b0L36000007xRItEAM"}, "Id": "a0M36000007xRItEAM", "OwnerId": "00536000002yKlTAAU", "IsDeleted": false, "Name": "Fresh", "Landing_Stop_Date__c": null, "Service_Exit_Date__c": null},{"attributes": {"type": "Silo__c", "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Silo__c/b0L36000007xRItEAM"}, "Id": "a0M36000007xRItEAM", "OwnerId": "00536000002yKlTAAU", "IsDeleted": false, "Name": "Fresh", "Landing_Stop_Date__c": null, "Service_Exit_Date__c": null},{"attributes": {"type": "Silo__c", "url": "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Silo__c/b0L36000007xRItEAM"}, "Id": "a0M36000007xRItEAM", "OwnerId": "00536000002yKlTAAU", "IsDeleted": false, "Name": "Fresh", "Landing_Stop_Date__c": null, "Service_Exit_Date__c": null}]
```

The above is very similar to the JSON I get from the query out of simple salesforce.

The below is supposed to turn it into jsonl while also fixing the datetime issues.

The problem is I have to get rid of the attributes section as it is not used.  the below code is the latest attempt, but all that results in is the same record over and over again. (the above is repeated data, so I would expect it to be the same if you ran it through)

```
for element in data :

        item = data.pop()
        item.pop('attributes', None)

        tempdict = OrderedDict({})
        for k,v in item.items() :
            if 'date' in k.lower() or 'stamp' in k.lower() :
                if not v is None :
                    d = d_parse(v)
                    v = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')
                    tempdict[k.lower()] = v
            else :
                tempdict[k.lower()] = v

        with open(localFilePath+fileName.format(nextObj,fileCount), 'a') as outfile :
            outfile.write(json.dumps(tempdict))
            outfile.write('\n')
```

The problem is that for some reason 1/2 of the records are getting lost.  I am only getting 384 of 767 records into the file. I suspect the issue has to do with the pop and where it is occurring in the code.  How can I get rid of the attributes section without losing 1/2 the records in the pop?

Edit:

The following code throws an error (based on the comment):

```
for element in data :
data.pop('attributes', None)

tempdict = OrderedDict({})
for k,v in data.items() :
    if 'date' in k.lower() or 'stamp' in k.lower() :
        if not v is None :
            d = d_parse(v)
            v = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')
            tempdict[k.lower()] = v
    else :
        tempdict[k.lower()] = v

with open(localFilePath+fileName.format(nextObj,fileCount), 'a') as outfile :
    outfile.write(json.dumps(tempdict))
    outfile.write('\n')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "child_sfdc_etl.py", line 417, in <module>
    sfToS3(fileCount, sf, nextObj)
  File "child_sfdc_etl.py", line 206, in sfToS3
    send_temp_jsonl_to_s3(data, nextObj, s3, s3Destination, fileCount, s3Path)
  File "child_sfdc_etl.py", line 254, in send_temp_jsonl_to_s3
    data.pop('attributes', None)
TypeError: pop() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

The code without the None also throws an error:

```
for element in data :
data.pop('attributes')

tempdict = OrderedDict({})
for k,v in data.items() :
    if 'date' in k.lower() or 'stamp' in k.lower() :
        if not v is None :
            d = d_parse(v)
            v = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')
            tempdict[k.lower()] = v
    else :
        tempdict[k.lower()] = v

with open(localFilePath+fileName.format(nextObj,fileCount), 'a') as outfile :
    outfile.write(json.dumps(tempdict))
    outfile.write('\n')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "child_sfdc_etl.py", line 417, in <module>
    sfToS3(fileCount, sf, nextObj)
  File "child_sfdc_etl.py", line 206, in sfToS3
    send_temp_jsonl_to_s3(data, nextObj, s3, s3Destination, fileCount, s3Path)
  File "child_sfdc_etl.py", line 254, in send_temp_jsonl_to_s3
    data.pop('attributes')
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Why are you doing the ```item = data.pop()``` at all? I think the problem is that you're altering the collection being iterated over while iterating over it. I would just remove the first pop call.

Comment: ifI try a data.pop('attributes', None) it gives an error. Traceback posted in edit.

Comment: You're iterating over a collection called ```data```, for which each element is referred to by the variable ```element``` you declared in the for loop, so you need to do ```element.pop()``` rather than ```data.pop()```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with how iteration is implemented in Python. As others have pointed out, the culprit is

```
for element in data :
    item = data.pop()
    <...>
```

Sequence iterator in Python keeps the index of the current element to determine what to return next (it's impossible, in the general case, to correctly iterate over a sequence if it's being altered in the process, so this is not a bug).

You take one item (starting from the beginning of the list) as `element`. Then you take and remove [the last item](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list%20pop#mutable-sequence-types) in the list as `item` and completely ignore `element`. The next iteration, `element` will be the item after the previous `element`. And so on. As a consequence, you will only process the second half of the initial list, in reverse order.

---

Remove `data.pop()` and use `element`.

Comment: Thanks to you both; I appreciate the lesson.